# Does $(m+1) + m2 + (m - 1)2^{2} \ldots + 2^{m}$ equal something simpler?

Tags: calculus, elementary-number-theory

Does  $(m + 1) + m2 + (m - 1)2^{2} \ldots + 2^{m}$ equal something simpler, where $m\in \mathbb{N}$? Excuse me if it is too simple, I am bit tired.

Thanks.

Comment: instead of just downvoting, specify what is the problem, so I can learn.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but: A lot of people downvote if there is no evidence of effort on your part.

Comment: Excuse me what is sth simpler? (not native english, sorry)

Comment: @rlartiga "something simpler"

Comment: @Aditya thanks!

Comment: You've got bigger problems than texting slang. For one thing, while $m2$ is technically valid, it makes me wonder if it really means what you want it to mean. Do you mean twice $m$? That would normally be written as $2m$. Or do you mean $m$ squared? That would be written $m^2$. I doubt you mean $m_2$, but I can't rule that out.

Comment: @Lisa, what else did you want to know at the problem where you placed a bounty? Note that, as far as I know, the person who originally answered is no longer active on MSE

Comment: @Lisa, please take a look at http://math.blogoverflow.com/2014/08/23/binary-quadratic-forms-over-the-rational-integers-and-class-numbers-of-quadratic-%EF%AC%81elds/ perhaps you will get some ideas for a focused question.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a hint, and a good trick in general, called diagonalization.

Write your sum in the form:

```
1 + 1 + 1 + ... + 1
    2 + 2 + ... + 2 
        4 + ... + 4
            ...
                 2^m
```

And compute the sum by columns rather than rows.

Answer (score 2):

You'll find essentially the same thing [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/903955/average-length-of-a-bitstring).

But note that that it looks like your sum should end with $2^{m-1}$ and not $2^m$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{i=0}^m (m+1-i)2^{i}=(m+1)\sum_{i=0}^m 2^i- \sum_{i=0}^m i2^{i}$$

At that point you should be able to calculate it.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}S=(m+1)+&2m\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;+2^2(m-1)+2^2(m-2)+...2^{m-1}\\2S=\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;&2(m+1)+2^2m\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;+2^3(m-1)+...(m-(m-2))2^{m-1}+2^m\end{align}$$
Subtract those:
$$S=(m+1)-2-2^2...-2^{m-1}-2^m=(m+1)-2(2^m-1)$$